# Indexing and other errors when using variable number of command-line arguments

Tags: python, indexing, argv

I am working my way through CS50's Introduction to Programming with Python. For the current problem I am supposed to write a program which involves:

> - Expects zero or two command-line arguments:
>
>   - Zero if the user would like to output text in a random font.
>   - Two if the user would like to output text in a specific font, in which case the first of the two should be `-f` or `--font`, and the
>     second of the two should be the name of the font.
> - Prompts the user for a str of text.
> - Outputs that text in the desired font.
> - If the user provides two command-line arguments and the first is not `-f` or `--font` or the second is not the name of a font, the program
>   should exit via `sys.exit` with an error message.

The code I have tried so far is included below. Problems include:

- When I enter no arguments in the command line I get `IndexError: list index out of range`
- When I enter 2 arguments and the first argument is not `-f` or `--f` the `sys.exit` is not executing as it should.

```
import sys
import random

fonts = ['fontA', 'fontB']

def main():
    s = input("Text: ")
    if len(sys.argv) == 0:
         print(print_random(s))
    elif len(sys.argv) == 2 and (sys.argv[1] == "-f" or sys.argv[1] == "--font") and sys.argv[2] in fonts:
        print(print_argument(s))
    else: 
        sys.exit()

def set_font(font):
    pass  # dummy implementation

def print_random(s):
    set_font(font=random.choice(fonts))
    # render_text(s)        
    
def print_argument(s):
    set_font(font=sys.argv[2])
    # render_text(s)

main()
```

Comment: If `len(sys.argv) == 2` then `sys.argv[2]` is invalid.

Comment: How do you know that `sys.exit()` is not executed?

Comment: It was still printing the input in the font I entered as the second argument even when my first argument wasn't '-f' or '--font'. It's working now, thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

len(sys.argv) should be == 3.

If you type

```py
print(str(sys.argv))
```

before

```py
if len(sys.argv) == 0:
```

you will understand